# Formatting Math.Pow Output

Tags: c#, formatting

I hate to ask such a dumb question, but I'm just starting out, so here goes.

```
myString = "2 to 2.5 power is " + Math.Pow(2, 2.5);
```

I want to format the resulting number to 4 decimal places and show the string in a MessageBox.  I can't seem to figure this out or find the answer in the book.  Thanks!

Comment: Not a dumb question, the docs around this are abysmal.

Comment: The only foolish question is the one left unasked.

Comment: .NET format string cheat sheet:  http://john-sheehan.com/blog/net-cheat-sheets/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The ToString method should do the trick. You might need to look it up in the MSDN to find more formatting options.

```
Math.Pow(2, 2.5).ToString("N4")
```

Answer (score 3):

To show a `string` in a `MessageBox` you use [`MessageBox.Show`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.messagebox.show.aspx). In particular, there is an [overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/519bytz3.aspx) accepting a single `string` parameter that will be displayed in the `MessageBox`. Thus, we need

```
string s = // our formatted string
MessageBox.Show(s);
```

Now, let's figure out what our `string` is. A useful method here is [`String.Format`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format.aspx). A useful reference here is the [Standard Numeric Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx) page on MSDN. In particular, I draw your attention to the [fixed-point specifier `"F"` or `"f"`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx#FFormatString):

> The fixed-point ("F) format specifier converts a number to a string of the form "-ddd.ddd…" where each "d" indicates a digit (0-9). The string starts with a minus sign if the number is negative.

The precision specifier indicates the desired number of decimal places.

Thus, we want

```
double result = Math.Pow(2, 2.5);
string s = String.Format("2 to 2.5 power is {0:F4}", result);
```

so, putting it all together,

```
double result = Math.Pow(2, 2.5);
string s = String.Format("2 to 2.5 power is {0:F4}", result);
MessageBox.Show(s);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
string.format("2 to 2.5 power is {0:0.000}", Math.Pow(2, 2.5));
```

Comment: That's three not four places, and the result is not in a `MessageBox`.

Answer (score 1):

```
Math.Pow(2, 2.5).ToString("N4")
```

is what you want I think.

[more formatting options](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fht0f5be(VS.80).aspx)

Comment: See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx for all options. Maybe D4 is better.

Comment: I don't think so, my mistake at first.  D4 will give the correct number of digits before the decimal point

Answer (score 1):

It's not a dumb question: several of the other answers are wrong.

```
MessageBox.Show(string.Format("2 to 2.5 power is {0:F4}", Math.Pow(2, 2.5)));
```